# Benefits of of view controls

Tags: asp.net

What are the benefits of using a datagrid vs repeater vs ListView control (asp.net 3.5)?
Or when would you use one and not the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView gives you near-total control over the markup and look of the data.  Use this if you need or want a specific layout

GridViews/DataGrid are designed to display information in a tabular format.  Use these if your data lends itself to being displayed as a table.

[This article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/The_ListView_Dominates_The_Repeater.aspx) discusses why the ListView is superior to the Repeater control.